# Manipulating checkboxes that were created from v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for, v-model

this is my first time posting, so sorry for any inconvenience.

I am having problems with vue-js, that is with its component manipulation.
I am creating some checkboxes from an array, which have a String called property and a boolean called checked.

Here is my array:

```
checkedRequests: [
    {
      property: 'cid',
      checked: true
    },
    {
      property: 'companyName',
      checked: true
    },
    {
      property: 'gln',
      checked: true
    },
    {
      property: 'address',
      checked: true
    },
]
```

And here is my vue div:

```
<div class="checkDiv" v-for="item in checkedRequests" :key="item.property">
  <input type="checkbox" id="item.property" v-model="item.checked">
  <label for="item.property">{{ item.property }}</label>
  <br>
</div>
```

My Problem is that when i try to check or uncheck any boxes, only my first property is getting manipulated, e.g 'cid'. In other words: If I click on address for example to toggle checked to false, 'cid' instead will toggle. The data is being portayed correctly but since the Array is false the checked boxes are alwas incorrect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You misidentified the problem. It's because you click on "address" instead of a checkbox. This is specific to how labels work and this is solved the way the answer shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have `id="item.property"` and `for="item.property"` as a string, using a binding `:id="item.property"` and `:for="item.property"` should solve your problem

```
  <div class="checkDiv" v-for="item in checkedRequests" :key="item.property">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="item.property" v-model="item.checked" />
    <label :for="item.property">{{ item.property }}</label>
    <br />
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow yeah that worked. Didnt think the answer would have been so simple!
Thank you so much!